# scipy.optimize.curvefit: Asymmetric error in fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I try to fit a function to my data using `scipy.optimize.curvefit`.

```
Q=optimization.curve_fit(func,X,Y, x0,ERR)
```

and it works well.

However, now I am trying to use an asymmetric error and I have no idea how to do that - or even if it is possible.

By asymmetric error I mean that the error is not for example: `3+-0.5` but `3 +0.6 -0.2`. 
So that ERR is an array with two columns.

It would be great if somebody had an idea how to do that - or could me point to a different Python routine which might be able to do it.

That a snippet of the code I am using - but I am not sure it makes it clearer:

```
A=numpy.genfromtxt('WF.dat')
cc=A[:,4]
def func(A,a1,b1,c1):
    N=numpy.zeros(len(x))
    for i in range(len(x)):
        N[i]=1.0*erf(a1*(A[i,1]-c1*A[i,0]**b1))

return N


x0   = numpy.array([2.5  , -0.07 ,-5.0])
Q=optimization.curve_fit(func,A,cc, x0, Error)
```

And Error=[ErP,ErM] (2 columns)

Comment: Can you post some (preferably runnable) code so that we can see the problem in more detail?

Comment: Can't you simply convert `3 +0.6 -0.2` into `3.2 +/- 0.4`?

Comment: not really. That would defeat the purpose of having such precise errors.

Comment: This problem might be more fun for people to tackle if you did as Mr E suggested and include a simple, runnable example that highlights the problem. Instead of loading data from a file, generate an asymmetric gaussian and add some random noise (np.random.random). Then solutions can try to fit this and get an asymmetric error for the mean.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version, I am afraid it is not doable. `curve_fit` is a wrap around the popular Fortran library `minipack`. Check the source code of `\scipy_install_path\optimize\minipack.py`, you will see: (line 498-509):

```
if sigma is None:
    func = _general_function
else:
    func = _weighted_general_function
    args += (1.0/asarray(sigma),)
```

Basically what it means is that of `sigma` is not provided, then the unweighted Levenberg-Marquardt method in `minipack` will be called. If `sigma` is provided, then the weighted LM will be called. That implies, if `sigma` is to be provided, it must be provided as a array of the same length of `X` or `Y`.

That means if you want to have asymmetric error residue on `Y`, you have to come up with some modification to your target function, as @Jaime suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Least squares algorithm like `curve_fit` or `scipy.optimize.leastsq` will not be able to do this because the loss function is quadratic, and so symmetric for positive and negative error.

I haven't seen any models for this and maybe PAIDA can handle it, as DanHickstein mentioned.

Otherwise, you could use the nonlinear optimizers like `optimize.fmin` and construct your own asymmetric loss function.

```
def loss_function(params, ...):
    error = (y - func(x, params))
    error_neg = (error < 0)
    error_squared = error**2 / (error_neg * sigma_low + (1 - error_neg) * sigma_upp))
    return error_squared.sum()
```

and minimize this with `fmin` or `fmin_bfgs`.

(I never tried this.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like the [PAIDA](http://paida.sourceforge.net/) package might do fits with asymmetric errors:

http://paida.sourceforge.net/documentation/fitter/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A solution, which I've used frequently, is to draw realisations (say 100-1000) from a split-normal distribution, and run your fitting algorithm on each of these realisations with the error set to 0.0. You'll then have 100-1000 best-fitting parameters, from which you can simply take the median, along with any error estimate you want to use.