# How to compute standard error from ODR results?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, regression, curve-fitting

I use `scipy.odr` in order to make a fit with uncertainties on both x and y following this question [Correct fitting with scipy curve_fit including errors in x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058792/correct-fitting-with-scipy-curve-fit-including-errors-in-x/26085136#26085136)

After the fit I would like to compute the uncertainties on the parameters. Thus I look at the square root of the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix. I get :

```
>>> print(np.sqrt(np.diag(output.cov_beta)))
[ 0.17516591  0.33020487  0.27856021]
```

But in the `Output` there is also `output.sd_beta` which is, according to the [doc on odr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.odr.Output.html#scipy.odr.Output)

> Standard errors of the estimated parameters, of shape (p,).

But, it does not give me the same results :

```
>>> print(output.sd_beta)
[ 0.19705029  0.37145907  0.31336217]
```

**EDIT**

This is an example on a notebook : https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/gvallverdu/cookbook/blob/master/fit_odr.ipynb

With least square

```
stop reason: ['Sum of squares convergence']
        params: [ -1.94792946  11.03369235  -5.43265555]
          info: 1
       sd_beta: [ 0.26176284  0.49877962  0.35510071]
sqrt(diag(cov): [ 0.25066236  0.47762805  0.34004208]
```

With ODR

```
stop reason: ['Sum of squares convergence']
        params: [-1.93538595  6.141885   -3.80784384]
          info: 1
       sd_beta: [ 0.6941821   0.88909997  0.17292514]
sqrt(diag(cov): [ 0.01093697  0.01400794  0.00272447]
```

Comment: Did ODR converge? What is `output.reason`?

Comment: attribute `output.stopreason` is 'Iteration limit reached'. I did explicit odr with `fit_type=0`. The fit looks like good but maybe the number of iteration is not enough ! `output.info` is 4.

Comment: I don't think you can trust `cov_beta` and `sd_beta` if ODR hasn't converged on a solution. Try setting `maxiter` to something large, or check `output.stopreason` and call `output = odr.reset(<more steps>)` if ODR hasn't converged yet.

Comment: Yes, without convergence you can talk nonsense. I run odr until it reaches convergence. I edit the question with the notebook example. With the least square approach `sd_beta` et `cov_beta` are closed each other. But with explicit ODR there  are strong differences.

Comment: Interesting. It seems that sqrt(diag(sd_cov)) is a scalar multiple of sd_beta (in your example the scaling parameter is 0.01575519).

Comment: Yes, I look at two other examples on more "real" data and again `sb_beta` and `sqrt(diag(sb_cov))` are proportional. But the coefficient is not always the same, I got 0.6981417 or 0.737385

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason for the discrepancy is that `sd_beta` is scaled by the residual variance, whereas `cov_beta` isn't.

`scipy.odr` is an interface for the ODRPACK FORTRAN library, which is thinly wrapped in `__odrpack.c`. `sd_beta` and `cov_beta` are recovered by indexing into the `work` vector that's used internally by the FORTRAN routine. The indices of their first elements in `work` are variables named `sd` and `vcv` (see [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2526df72e5d4ca8bad6e2f4b3cbdfbc33e805865/scipy/odr/__odrpack.c#L361)).

From the [ODRPACK documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/external/odrpack_guide.pdf) (p.85):

> **`WORK(SDI)`** is the first element of a `p × 1` array `SD` containing
>   the standard deviations `̂σβK` of the function parameters `β`, i.e., the
>   square roots of the diagonal entries of the covariance matrix, where
>
> ```
> WORK(SDI-1+K) = SD(K) = ̂V 1/2 β (K, K) = ̂σβK
> ```
>
> for `K = 1,... ,p`.
>
> **`WORK(VCVI)`** is the first element of a `p × p` array `VCV` containing
>   the values of the covariance matrix of the parameters `β` ***prior to
>   scaling by the residual variance***, where
>
> ```
> WORK(VCVI-1+I+(J-1)*(NP)) = VCV(I,J) = ̂σ⁻²V β(I, J)
> ```
>
> for `I = 1,... ,p` and `J = 1,... ,p`.

In other words, `np.sqrt(np.diag(output.cov_beta * output.res_var))` will give you the same result as `output.sd_beta`.

I've opened a bug report [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6842).

Comment: Looking at the doc of matlab, the standard error (stdx) seems to be equivalent to the sd_beta of scipy.odr : https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lscov.html Matlab does multiply by the error.

Comment: The line `np.sqrt(np.diag(output.cov_beta * output.res_var))` indeed returns the same value as `output.sd_beta`, but what's not clear to me is: which of these two outputs is the proper standard deviation for the fitted parameters? (Asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638882/estimate-the-standard-deviation-of-fitted-parameters-in-scipy-odr)

Comment: ali_m shouldn't it be the other way around? I.e.: "*`cov_beta` is scaled by the residual variance, whereas `sd_beta` isn't*".

Comment: @Gabriel No, `output.cov_beta` *ought* to be scaled by the residual variance, but it isn't by default (hence why you need to multiply it by `output.res_var`).