# Convergence when utilizing scipy.odr module to find best-fit parameters when there is only horizontal errorbars

Tags: scipy, linear-regression, curve-fitting, least-squares, errorbar

I am trying to fit a piecewise (otherwise linear) function to a set of experimental data. The form of the data is such that there is only horizontal error bars and no vertical error bars. I am familiar with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` module but that works when there is only vertical error bars corresponding to the *dependent variable y*. After searching for my specific need, I came across the following post where it explains about the possibility of using `scipy.odr` module when errorbars are those of *independent variable x*. ([Correct fitting with scipy curve_fit including errors in x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058792/correct-fitting-with-scipy-curve-fit-including-errors-in-x/26085136#26085136))

Attached is my version of the code which tries to find best-fit parameters using ODR methodology. It actually draws best-fit function and it seems it's working. However, after changing initial (educated guess) values and trying to extract best-fit parameters, I am getting the same guessed parameters I inserted initially. This means that the method is not convergent and you can verify this by printing `output.stopreason` and getting

> ['Numerical error detected']

So, my question is whether this methodology is consistent with my function being piecewise and if not, if there is any other correct methodology to adopt in such cases?

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from scipy.odr import ODR, Model, Data, RealData

x_array=array([8.2,8.6,9.,9.4,9.8,10.2,10.6,11.,11.4,11.8])
x_err_array=array([0.2]*10)
y_array=array([-2.05179545,-1.64998354,-1.49136169,-0.94200805,-0.60205999,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.])
y_err_array=array([0]*10)


# Linear Fitting Model
def func(beta, x):
    return piecewise(x, [x < beta[0]], [lambda x:beta[1]*x-beta[1]*beta[0], lambda x:0.0])

data  = RealData(x_array, y_array, x_err_array, y_err_array)
model = Model(func)

odr = ODR(data, model, [10.1,1.02])
odr.set_job(fit_type=0)
output = odr.run()

f, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10,10))

ax1.errorbar(x_array, y_array, xerr = x_err_array, yerr = y_err_array, ecolor = 'blue', elinewidth = 3, capsize = 3, linestyle = '')
ax1.plot(x_array, func(output.beta, x_array), 'blue',  linestyle = 'dotted', label='Best-Fit')

ax1.legend(loc='lower right', ncol=1, fontsize=12)
ax1.set_xlim([7.95, 12.05])
ax1.set_ylim([-2.1, 0.1])
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='upper')) 
ax1.set_ylabel('$y$', fontsize=12)
ax1.set_xlabel('$x$', fontsize=12)
ax1.set_xscale("linear", nonposx='clip')
ax1.set_yscale("linear", nonposy='clip')
ax1.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()  
ax1.get_yaxis().tick_left()

f.subplots_adjust(top=0.98,bottom=0.14,left=0.14,right=0.98)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error of 0 for y is causing problems. Make it small but not zero, e.g. `1e-16`. Doing so the fit converges. It also does if you omit the `y_err_array` when defining `RealData` but I am not sure what happens internally in that case.