# What is the best way to correct a curve to data points in python?

Tags: python, time-series, curve-fitting, curve

I am looking for a way to correct a curve based on multiple data points. I have a time series with 2k+ rows represented by [x1,y1] (blue line). Measured data points are at time points [x2,y2] (red points). I need to correct the curve to the data points. Thanks for the help!

Just to clarify, I am not looking to fit a curve to this data, I am hoping to transform the blue curve to fit the red data points for a much larger blue line data set.

'''

```
x1 = [2.99,3.60,4.55,6.90,13.10,14.20,15.07,15.60,16.44,17.72,18.10,18.84,19.94,20.44,21.00,22.45,23.10,23.77,25.44,26.44,28.64,30.2,33.0,36.5,38.60]
y1 = [4.7, 3.9, 5.1, 5.9, 18.9, 22.9, 20.6, 22.3, 26.1, 25.9, 26.3, 27.0, 27.4, 27.8, 28.0, 28.4, 28.6, 29.0, 28.7, 27.8, 27.6, 27.9, 27.9, 27.7, 28.3]

x2 = [3.60, 13.10, 15.60, 18.10, 20.44, 23.10, 26.44, 38.60]
y2 = [0.1, 7.5, 24.45, 69.4, 97.6, 109.2, 103.74, 103.22]
```

'''
[Data Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZNaR.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct fitting with scipy curve\_fit including errors in x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058792/correct-fitting-with-scipy-curve-fit-including-errors-in-x)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scipy+curve+fit

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: ...what do you mean by "correct"?

Comment: Apologies I should have been more specific here. I am not looking to fit a curve. I am hoping to transform my blue curve to the red points.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to plot it as scatter plot, you can try

```
plt.scatter(x1, y1)
plt.show()
```

[source](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)