# How to take into account the data's uncertainty (standard deviation) when fitting with scipy.linalg.lstsq?

Tags: python, least-squares, data-fitting

I am trying to surface fit 3d data (z is a function of x and y). I have assymetrical error bars for each point. I would like the fit to take this uncertainty into account.

I am using scipy.linalg.lstsq(). It does not have any option for uncertainties in its arguments.

I am trying to adapt some code found on [this page](http://inversionlabs.com/2016/03/21/best-fit-surfaces-for-3-dimensional-data.html).

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create data with x and y random over [-2, 2], and z a Gaussian function of x and y.
np.random.seed(12345)
x = 2 * (np.random.random(500) - 0.5)
y = 2 * (np.random.random(500) - 0.5)

def f(x, y):
    return np.exp(-(x + y ** 2))

z = f(x, y)

data = np.c_[x,y,z]

# regular grid covering the domain of the data
mn = np.min(data, axis=0)
mx = np.max(data, axis=0)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(mn[0], mx[0], 20), np.linspace(mn[1], mx[1], 20))
XX = X.flatten()
YY = Y.flatten()

# best-fit quadratic curve (2nd-order)
A = np.c_[np.ones(data.shape[0]), data[:,:2], np.prod(data[:,:2], axis=1), data[:,:2]**2]
C,_,_,_ = scipy.linalg.lstsq(A, data[:,2])

# evaluate it on a grid
Z = np.dot(np.c_[np.ones(XX.shape), XX, YY, XX*YY, XX**2, YY**2], C).reshape(X.shape)

# plot points and fitted surface using Matplotlib
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.2)
ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2], c='r', s=50)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.axis('equal')
ax.axis('tight')
```

Comment: Hi, did you read the docu? **scipy.linalg.lstsq...Compute least-squares solution to equation Ax = b.** So, I'd say it is not really suited for your exponential.

Comment: Also have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19116519/803359

Comment: ... thanks but change it to z=x² + y² if you prefer

Comment: Least squares fitting, like any other tool, works if your data satisfies, or at least almost satisfies certain assumptions. Your data does not, so least squares is not the crowbar for your nail.

Comment: Thanks Mikuszefski. Thanks Mad Physicist but sorry, how do you know my data does not satisfy certain assumptions? Which assumptions are you referring to?

Comment: Well, you don't have a Gaussian to fit, you have random data with a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: in 1D this can be handled by scipy.stats.norm.fit` but not in 2D

Comment: This data is simulated for the purpose of this question. And if you actually run the code, the fit is perfect. Which other fitting methodology do you believe would be more appropriate to use for asteroseismology (fmin and fmax in x and y, based on an fft, and temperature in z) ?

Comment: Sorry, got it wrong, so you really build a Gaussian over random (x,y), OK. if you want to fit this with asymmetric errors you could try to build your own cost funvtion and use `scipy.optimize.leastsq`

Comment: scipy.optimize.curvefit has the possibility of using error bars so I might use that instead of scipy.linalg.lstsq

Comment: @Tommy95. That's a much better idea.