# How to fit data with asymmetric error bars

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting, errorbar, asymmetric

I hope someone can help me with the following problem:
I have a set of data, each one with the shape [y_best, y_min, y_max], where y_min and y_max are the extremes of the error bar; just to give an idea:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5mmq.png)

I want to fit this data in Python3, but i don't know how to do because of these asymmetric error bars.. someone can help me?

Comment: That question is too broad for stackoverflow. You should provide more details, e.g. what frameworks you want to use, and ideally provide some code snippet of what you have tried so far, so it becomes a more concrete problem :)

Comment: a quick internet search may also help. Found this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19129112/803359 Does more or less what I'd have suggested.